# Running conan from powershell script

Tags: powershell, conan

Is there a way of using conan package manager commands in a bat file or ps1 file?
Or any other automated way..

I want to automate the conan install / build / package commands.

NOTE: All commands runs smoothly as single calls from PS already.

Comment: So... what's the question? Does something break if you put each command in a text file, save it as `script.ps1`, and then execute it?

Comment: Yes. Conan will generate .bat  files on Windows.

Comment: Please post the exact script + error messages in full, _as plain text_. Easier to help you troubleshoot when we can copy-paste rather than transcribing off a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.. don't know why it failed the first time since it was rather straightforward after all. I think the comment from Mathias helped out since it was rather convincing that it should go.

```
$thisDir= Get-Location
$buildDir = "$thisDir\build"
if (Test-Path $buildDir)
{
    Remove-Item -Path $buildDir -Force
}
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $buildDir
Set-Location -Path $buildDir
conan install .. --update --build=missing
conan build ..
conan package ..
Set-Location -Path $thisDir
```